# Data Save in File except Database

Tags: c#

I am new to Windows form application I want to Save Data in file except in (Sql) or database.I tried many things and I am able to store only one value in text file using it

```
TextWriter txt = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:\\Tahir\\ScaleSystemDataSave\\First.txt");
txt.Write(txtFirsrWeight.Text);
txt.Close();
```

but I Want to Store an Object in file how can I Do it My object is like this

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FirstTime obj = new FirstTime();
    obj.CardNo = txtCardNo.Text;
    obj.DateTime = txtDateTimePicker.Value;
    obj.VehicleNo = txtVehicalNo.Text;
    obj.WeightType = Convert.ToString(cbxWeigtType.SelectedItem);
    obj.FirstWeight = txtFirsrWeight.Text;
    if (rbtWithDriver.Checked == true)
    {
        obj.IsDriver = (int)Status.WithDriver;
    }
    else if (rbtWithouDriver.Checked == true)
    {
        obj.IsDriver = (int)Status.withOutDriver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the data from the text file and recreate the object at any time?

Comment: Please do **not** tag spam. Tags have specific meaning and are relevant here. Use the ones that actually apply to your question. Your question has absolutely nothing to do with Javascript, PHP, CSS, or OOP, so **none of those tags apply to your post**, and adding them is absolutely and totally wrong.

Comment: ok thanks sir to help me to improve my ability to ask question

Comment: **_Suggestion_:** Why not save your object in XML format? As this will be easy for you if you want to get data again from that file.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options available to you.

1. Format the text file yourself like a comma delimited file and then read the file back in, parse it and assign the values back to your object.
2. Use a known serialization technique such as XML or JSON.

Below is an example of JSON serialization that achieves what you need.

```
var first = new FirstTime()
            {
                CardNo = "121515611",
                Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
                VehicleNo = "MNRG23434",
                WeightType = "MyWeight",
                FirstWeight = "FirstWeight"
            };

            var fileText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(first);

            TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:\\First.txt");
            txt.Write(fileText);
            txt.Close();

            var fileStream = File.Open("C:\\First.txt",FileMode.Open);

            var fileReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
            var contents = fileReader.ReadToEnd();

            var restoredObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirstTime>(contents);
```

This stores the data in format as per the below

```
{"CardNo":"121515611","Date":"2017-03-16T00:00:00+00:00","VehicleNo":"MNRG23434","WeightType":"MyWeight","FirstWeight":"FirstWeight"}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks sir its proper answer of my question I am very thankful to you

Comment: Sir its working but issue is that when 2nd object is added to same file then it overwrite the first object whats about it

Comment: Hello.. You need to open the file with "FileMode.Append".. or you overwrite the file..